# Categorical search (like restaurants,hospitals..etc) for given particular location (Not our location)

Tags: android, google-maps

```
        String m = "geo:" + location + "?q=hospitals";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(m);
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        startActivity(mapIntent);
```

In the above code, the location is in the form (latitude, longitude) (e.g. 15.34322, 33.546723).

This is my code to search and launch maps for a custom location provided by a different app. Instead of showing results near the given location it is launching with results near my current location. Can anyone help me understand the issue and resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents)

```
// Search for restaurants in San Francisco
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:37.7749,-122.4194?q=hospitals");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);
```

In your case, just substitute the given "geo:37.7749,-122.4194" with the desired coordinates.

The case that shows the hospitals(or restaurants["q=restaurants" etc]) nearby of the users' location, is if you dont specify the geo coordinates, like so:

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("q=restaurants");
```

Comment: Hello, I did the same thing which is mentioned in the documentation but even then it shows hospitals at nearby location instead of custom location which is mentioned.

Comment: Are you sure? check this project i created:
[link] (https://github.com/AlexSemer/FindHospitals)

Comment: Thank you,yes i got after trying with different location,but when i tried with this location("18.553433,73.824670") it used to show near by hospitals of me instead of near by hospitals of custom location.